# Categorical dtype changes after using melt

Tags: python, pandas

In answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52749898/6671176), I found that after using `melt` on a pandas dataframe, a column that was previously an ordered Categorical dtype becomes an `object`. Is this intended behaviour?

Note: not looking for a solution, just wondering if there is any reason for this behaviour or if it's not intended behavior.

**Example:**

Using the following dataframe `df`:

```
  Cat  L_1  L_2  L_3
0   A    1    2    3
1   B    4    5    6
2   C    7    8    9

df['Cat'] = pd.Categorical(df['Cat'], categories = ['C','A','B'], ordered=True)

# As you can see `Cat` is a category
>>> df.dtypes
Cat    category
L_1       int64
L_2       int64
L_3       int64
dtype: object

melted = df.melt('Cat')

>>> melted
  Cat variable  value
0   A      L_1      1
1   B      L_1      4
2   C      L_1      7
3   A      L_2      2
4   B      L_2      5
5   C      L_2      8
6   A      L_3      3
7   B      L_3      6
8   C      L_3      9
```

Now, if I look at `Cat`, it's become an object:

```
>>> melted.dtypes
Cat         object
variable    object
value        int64
dtype: object
```

**Is this intended?**

Comment: Super interesting. I can't imagine this is intended, and you might consider submitting an issue on `pandas`' GitHub.

Comment: pandas does some weird stuff when it reshapes the data. I found some odd behavior when [transposing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882090/why-does-transposing-a-dataframe-with-strings-and-timedeltas-convert-the-dtype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/9dc9d805fe58cf32a8a3c8ab2277517eaf73d4c6#diff-9d24108841e0a76fe806a808d84f4561) code . 0.22.0(My old version)

```
 for col in id_vars:
        mdata[col] = np.tile(frame.pop(col).values, K)
     mcolumns = id_vars + var_name + [value_name]
```

Which will return the datatype object with `np.tile`.

It has been fixed in 0.23.4(After I update my `pandas`)

```
df.melt('Cat')
Out[6]: 
  Cat variable  value
0   A      L_1      1
1   B      L_1      4
2   C      L_1      7
3   A      L_2      2
4   B      L_2      5
5   C      L_2      8
6   A      L_3      3
7   B      L_3      6
8   C      L_3      9
df.melt('Cat').dtypes
Out[7]: 
Cat         category
variable      object
value          int64
dtype: object
```

More info how it fixed :

```
for col in id_vars:
    id_data = frame.pop(col)
    if is_extension_type(id_data): # here will return True , then become concat not np.tile
        id_data = concat([id_data] * K, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        id_data = np.tile(id_data.values, K)
    mdata[col] = id_data
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice to see they fixed it! FYI, I found this when I was using `pandas` '0.21.1'